# Ovals drawn on canvas do not display until I manually zoom (scale)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Fairly new to python, maybe ~1 yr of experience total.  Using python 3.8.5 and tkinter.

Project involves building a GUI, having problems with a map on it.  In one of the frames, I have a canvas.  On this canvas, I draw circles to represent locations, the user can pan/zoom using the mouse, click on the circles for information, etc.

The Problem is during the initial drawing of the map.  I run the readCSV() function, it loads the locations and statuses correctly (manually checked the 'data' list while debugging), then it runs the draw_MapDots() function.  The canvas is blank... until I do a mouse-wheel zoom, then all the locations display correctly.

The Locations are read from a CSV:

```
def readCSV():
    global maplbl

    global mapdot_maxx
    global mapdot_maxy
    global data
    global tagdic


    try:
        f=open(filedialog.askopenfilename(),'r')

        reader = csv.reader(f)
        data = list(reader)
        f.close

        ##### CSV Format ####
        ## Data stored in CSV are in the following format:
        ## [Tag ID], [x coordinate], [y coordinate], [read status]
        ##

        for point in data:
            tagdic[point[0]]= point[1:]
            mapdot_maxx = max ([float(point[1]), mapdot_maxx])
            mapdot_maxy = max ([float(point[2]), mapdot_maxy])
        
        draw_MapDots()

        #### trying random stuff to to get canvas to display
        #
        #map_canvas.scale('all',0,0 , .2, .2)
        #map_canvas.xview_moveto(mapdot_maxx/2)
        #map_canvas.yview_moveto(mapdot_maxy/2)
        #map_canvas.update_idletasks()
        #MainWindow.update_idletasks()

        maplbl.forget()
        maplbl = Label(frame_mapdisplay, text = "Tag Load Complete",font = ("", 24))
        maplbl.pack()

    

    except:
        data = [[]]
```

draw_MapDots function is here:

```
def draw_MapDots():
    global map_canvas

    global mapdotsize

    global mapdot_maxx
    global mapdot_maxy
    global data
    global tagdic

    map_canvas.delete("all") #Clears Map
    origin = map_canvas.create_oval(0,0,.1,.1,  fill = "white", tag = "origin") #Creates (0,0) dot

    #Creates a map of dots based on tag file opened
    if len(data)>1:
        for dot in data:
            x = float(dot[1])
            y = -float(dot[2])
            oval = map_canvas.create_oval(x-mapdotsize,y-mapdotsize,x+mapdotsize,y+mapdotsize,  fill = "red", activefill = "blue", tag = dot[0])
            if dot[3] == '1':
                map_canvas.itemconfigure(oval, fill = "green")
            if dot[3] == '1':
                map_canvas.itemconfigure(oval, fill = "yellow")

    map_canvas.config(scrollregion=map_canvas.bbox(ALL)) #Set bounding box for all objects to encompas created map dots
```

Scroll-Wheel zooming

```
def zoom_map(event):
    logging.debug(event)
    global mapdotsize
    scalefactor = .1
    if event.delta/120 < 0:
        map_canvas.scale('all',event.x ,event.y , 1-scalefactor, 1-scalefactor)
        mapdotsize *= 1-scalefactor
    else:
        map_canvas.scale('all',event.x ,event.y , 1+scalefactor, 1+scalefactor)
        mapdotsize *= 1+scalefactor
    
    map_canvas.config(scrollregion=map_canvas.bbox(ALL)) #Restricts canvas bounding box to the map dots

map_canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", zoom_map)
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing out the question, I finally realized what was happening.

My CSV numbers were rather large (in the hundreds to thousands range) and so when I initially drew the circles (mapdotsize = 18), they were getting drawn, but were just really far away.  Doing a mouse-drag didn't show them in the immediate area so I assumed that they were not being drawn.

Somehow, when I mouse-zoomed, [someone else please explain what is really happening] it appeared to 'snap' the view to a reasonable area inside of the drawing region that contains the map dots; it just looked like they "suddenly appeared".  I figured this out by dragging the map to the left a bunch more times than I had tried before and suddenly seeing the 'right' edge of my dots.

Comment: You could just delete the Q, if you found out an answer or you could include your inference with the post.

Comment: Tkinter coordinates are 16-bit.  Zooming in probably pushed your oval's positions past 64K, so they wrapped around, back into view.

Comment: Updating scrollregion will scroll the viewport to the map dots.